# how to add more options on django signup generic views?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

I know that Django has class-based generic views which give us ability to (for instance signup) signup users, but it has a little option and I want to add more fields to it, How can I do it?
Thanks;

## In the views.py

```
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy

class SignUpView(CreateView):
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    template_name = "profiles/signup.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('profiles_home')
```

## In the urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('profiles.views',
    url(r'^signup', SignUpView.as_view(), name="profiles_signup"),
    )
```

I want to add E-mail, First and Last name, ... fields.

Comment: What have you done so far to do that? You gotta share your code in here if you want to get help.

Comment: You need to create a custom registration page! instead of using `UserCreationForm`

Comment: Subclass `UserCreationForm` and your extra fields to it.

Comment: I know I can create my own tables for doing it, but I want to know if I can do it on `UserCreationForm`

Comment: @AlirezaGhaffari You can do it too , but the first one is much better! checkout http://jessenoller.com/blog/2011/12/19/quick-example-of-extending-usercreationform-in-django and following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745197/django-create-custom-usercreationform-basic