# Can the User model be overridden to make the email field required?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-authentication

For my application, the email field in the Django `User model` should be required, but by default it's optional.

I searched this question but most answers I found were talking about making the email field required in the customised `UserCreationForm` [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745197/django-create-custom-usercreationform):

```
class CustomUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    """Provide a view for creating users with only the requisite fields."""

    class Meta:
        model = User
        # Note that password is taken care of for us by auth's UserCreationForm.
        fields = ('username', 'email')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomUserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['email'].required = True
```

**but I want to make the email mandatory in the `User` model as well** because I was thinking maybe `ModelForm` are a frontend thing and the required condition maybe be turned off by the user by using the chrome dev tools, am I wrong? Will making the email required in `ModelForm` is same as making it required in the user `model` as well, **or can I override the user model to make the email required?**

Comment: A Form is *not* only frontend, if you use a form to process the data (typically constructing `CustomUserForm(request.POST)`, it will also validate, at the server side if the user has entered an `email` address).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Maybe ModelForm are a frontend thing and the required condition maybe be turned off by the user by using the chrome dev tools, am I wrong?

You are correct that a user can use tools to make an input item not required, in fact you can often alter the DOM and thus alter the HTML form, or even more simply make use of a tool like `curl` to make a POST request where you can post arbitrary data.

But a `Form` (and by extent an `ModelForm`) does *not* only render the form in HTML, it is also used to *validate* the data. This thus means that if you use a view with:

```
def my_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomUserForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            # …
        # …
    # …
```

then the `form.is_valid()` will return `False` if the user did not fill in an email address. A form is thus used to validate, clean data, store data in a model, and render a HTML form.

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

User.add_to_class('email', models.EmailField(blank=False))
```

Comment: Just now I tried this out but I was still able to create a user with the email field being left empty

Comment: if you add null=True please run makemigrations

Comment: Sorry I didn't quite get you, where do I need to add null=True? but I did run makemigrations

Comment: I tried this `User.add_to_class('email', models.EmailField(null=True, blank=False))` but I am getting the following error: ERRORS:
auth.User.email: (models.E006) The field 'email' clashes with the field 'email' from model 'auth.user'.

Comment: ok, we can change all class, let put the code

Comment: realle sorry, so tired yesterday, null=False.
User.add_to_class('email', models.EmailField(null=False, blank=False))
and run python manage.py makemigrations
and run python manage.py migrate

Answer (score 1):

in your settings file

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'yourapp.User'
```

in your models

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, Permission, Group
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _


class User(AbstractUser):
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(
        Group,
        verbose_name=_('groups'),
        blank=True,
        help_text=_(
            'The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions '
            'granted to each of their groups.'
        ),
        related_name="user_groups",
        related_query_name="user",
    )
    user_permissions = models.ManyToManyField(
        Permission,
        verbose_name=_('user permissions'),
        blank=True,
        help_text=_('Specific permissions for this user.'),
        related_name="user_permissions",
        related_query_name="user",
    )

    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']

    # here you can add new fields and attributes

    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            # here you can add pressiion
        )
```

in your admin

```
from custodia.models import User
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _


@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_display = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'customer', 'is_staff', 'is_active')
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('username', 'password')}),
        (_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')}),
        (_('Aditional info'), {'fields': ('your_new_fields',)}),
        (_('Permissions'), {
            'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'groups', 'user_permissions'),
        }),
        (_('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
    )

    list_filter = ('is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'is_active', 'groups', 'customer')
```

Comment: I am quite new to Django so I don't understand, like if we are inheriting from `AbstractUser` then why do we need to add so many things like `groups`, `user_permissions` etc. won't the AbstractUser take care of all this? Also, I don't understand the code in `admin.py`, what is it for?

Comment: the admin file is only need it if you are using the admin site